# How can I give a link to the caption

Tags: objective-c

Hey! I have made an application for iPhone that publishes audio file on Facebook. I used caption and description for that and now want to put link to the caption. Plz tell me how to achieve that.....

Thanx....!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/ is helpful. I used properties in my attachment dictionary and that worked.